# ‘platform’ import disappearing from selenium as a result of my script

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Linux ip-172-31-36-170 3.10.35-43.137.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 2 09:36:59 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Amazon Linux AMI release 2014.03
cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2014.03:ga

---

I've run into a weird problem with a script that uses selenium.webdriver.PhantomJS.

SYMPTOMS…
My script uses the following to start a phantomjs session

```
from selenium import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
(…)
def load_driver(self, _driver = "phantomjs", _path = "./phantomjs"):
        if   "phantom" in str(_driver).lower():
            self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(_path)
```

Fails with:
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver.' ; Screenshot: available via screen

HOWEVER, at the python command line, everything works fine…

```
from selenium import webdriver
_path = './phantomjs.exe'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(_path)
PLATFORM: Linux
platform.system() != 'Windows':  True
```

(I’ll explain “PLATFORM: Linux”, and “platform.system() != 'Windows':  True” below)

SO…
I traced the error to the “/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/service.py” and specifically this code…

```
def start(self):
    """
    """
    try:
        print "PLATFORM:", platform.system() #ADDED BY ME
        # FOLLOWING ADDED BY ME, NOW CAUSING THE ERROR
        print "platform.system() != 'Windows': ", platform.system() != 'Windows' 
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.service_args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                        close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows', # <-- THIS CAUSED ORIG PROB
                                        stdout=self._log, stderr=self._log)

    except Exception as e:
        raise WebDriverException("Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver.", e)
```

AND HERE’S THE ISSUE…
When I run the code at the python command line (see above) everything is fine, AND the responses to ‘platform.system()’ and “platform.system() != 'Windows' ” are correct.

However, when I run my script, the ‘platform.system()’ reports blank and “platform.system() != 'Windows' ” errors. (See actual output below).

So, for some reason, when my script loads selenium and runs…THE SELENIUM CODE loses the ‘platform’ import.

Thanks for the help!

ACTUAL OUTPUT BELOW (NOTICE that 'PLATFORM:' is followed by 'blank' (instead of 'Linux'), and the next line “platform.system() != 'Windows' ” triggers the error. These lines were added by me into the SELENIUM code, not my code!)

```
PLATFORM:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./agmarknet.py", line 834, in <module>
    username  = options.username      # --username
  File "./agmarknet.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.load_driver(driver, driver_path)
  File "./agmarknet.py", line 521, in load_driver
    self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/service.py", line 64, in start
    print "PLATFORM:", platform.system() #333
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/platform.py", line 1272, in system
    return uname()[0]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/platform.py", line 1239, in uname
    processor = _syscmd_uname('-p','')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/platform.py", line 995, in _syscmd_uname
    output = string.strip(f.read())
  File "./agmarknet.py", line 350, in _signal_handler
    self._cleanup()
  File "./agmarknet.py", line 194, in _cleanup
    self.driver.close()
AttributeError: 'Agmarknet' object has no attribute 'driver'
2014-05-18 12:42:40,281 - Agmarknet - INFO - Closing WebDriver...
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "./agmarknet.py", line 194, in _cleanup
    self.driver.close()
AttributeError: 'Agmarknet' object has no attribute 'driver'
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "./agmarknet.py", line 194, in _cleanup
    self.driver.close()
```

Comment: This is rather technical and should probably be a bug report in the appropriate issue tracker.

Comment: You may be right. Since it worked in the python window, I assumed it was something to do with MY script - and thought I'd try this first :-)